# Agreement of the adjective 'courts'

Tags: adjectifs, accord, pluriel, genre

If the adjective 'grand' is put in a plural feminine sentence it becomes 'grandes' so why does court not become 'courtes' in this sentance..... " Elle a les yeux bleus et les cheveux ________"

Comment: What made you think *cheveux* was feminine?

Answer (score 4):

*Cheveux* is masculine.

> Elle a les yeux bleus et les cheveux courts.
> Il a les yeux bleus, les cheveux courts et une longue barbe.

but of course if you use *court* it with a feminine noun, it will have an *e* in the end.

> Sa jupe est très courte.
>
> Elle ne porte que des jupes courtes ou des pantalons longs.

You can easily check the gender of nouns in a dictionary.

[cheveu /ʃə.vø ou /ʃfø/ **masculin**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheveu)

[jupe /ʒyp/ **féminin**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jupe)

Comment: ahh ok so when you talk about cheveux it changes you talking about the person but the hair instead. Thanks

Comment: @BenjaminCutting Well... the person isn't blue, the eyes are. The person isn't short, the hair is...  I hadn't seen your problem, I've expanded the examples.